# ImageResizer Basic Installation

Tags: asp.net, imageresizer

I'm developing a Windows Phone Application and I need to have an image resizing web service.

I've came across http://imageresizing.net/ and I have followed the simple IIS Installation

(http://imageresizing.net/docs/install/administrators) first guide.

but i'm getting an 500 error. I know it's too generic.

Any ideas what might fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

### [Enable detailed error messages](http://imageresizing.net/docs/geterror) as [suggested on the support page](http://imageresizing.net/support), then [read the troubleshooting guide](http://imageresizing.net/docs/troubleshoot).

'500' means 'Server error'.

Comment: After enabling the customErrors mode I got this.

Detailed Error Information:
Module    IIS Web Core
Notification    MapRequestHandler
Handler    StaticFile
Error Code    0x80070002
Requested URL    http://site:80/http:/localhost/iis-8.png?w=50
Physical Path   <path>
Logon Method    Anonymous
Logon User    Anonymous

seems I haven't mapped the request but also can't find a way to do that.

Comment: Please update your answer with the full error message  and what you have tried so far.